# VB: Invalid column name?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to implement a search function on a VB web app I have, and its throwing an error and I can't see why its giving me the error its suggesting.

I have followed this guide to implement a search on the grid view.

http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/1425.html

the error I get is: Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID'

Points to this line (32)

```
 Line 30:         Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
 Line 31:         Dim ds As New DataSet()
 Line 32:         da.Fill(ds)
 Line 33:         conn.Close()
 Line 34:         Return ds
```

Here is the code behind:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim cbSelect As Object

Private Property contacted As Object

Private Function CustomersData() As DataSet
    Dim text As String = "SELECT ID, contact,Sales_followUp, case_closed,week,year,
     [account_id], [product_name], [begin_date], [begin_request_date],
     [billing_country_code], [region], [billing_zip], [clear_name], 
     [clear_lower_email], [Territory], [Market Segment] AS column1, [AR Period] AS
     AR_Period, [Revenue Type] AS Revenue_Type, [Service Group] AS Service_Group, 
     [Sfdc Customer Id] AS Sfdc_Customer_Id, 
     [Sfdc Account Owner ID] AS Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID,  
     [Comments] FROM [BusinessSignups]"

    Dim connString As String = "Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=Support_Metrics;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxx"
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(text, conn)
    conn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds)
    conn.Close()
    Return ds
End Function

Private Function CustomersDataWithSearchText(ByVal field As String, ByVal searchText As String) As DataSet
    Dim text As String = "SELECT ID, [Territory],  [Sfdc Account Owner ID] AS Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID FROM [BusinessSignups] WHERE " & field & " LIKE '%" & searchText & "%'"
    Dim connString As String = "Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=Support_Metrics;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxx"
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(text, conn)
    conn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds)
    conn.Close()
    Return ds
End Function


Public Sub checkbox_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Protected Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 'Handles Button3.Click
    For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows 'itterate tru all rows
        Dim chkBox As CheckBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("cbSelect"), CheckBox) 'find the checkBox inside GridView
        Dim chkBox1 As CheckBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("Sales"), CheckBox) 'find the checkBox inside GridView
        Dim chkBox2 As CheckBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("Case"), CheckBox) 'find the checkBox inside GridView

        Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=Support_Metrics;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxx")
        Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand("update BusinessSignups set contact=@cbSelect, comments=@comments, Sales_followUp=@sales, Case_Closed=@Case where ID=@ID", sqlcon) 'this is an insert example, you can do update you can get the current gridView row id using gvRow.Cells(0).Text
        'Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand("insert into BusinessSignups (contacted) values (@cbSelect)", sqlcon) 'this is an insert example, you can do update you can get the current gridView row id using gvRow.Cells(0).Text
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", gvRow.Cells(10).Text)
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cbSelect", chkBox.Checked)
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sales", chkBox1.Checked) 'passing the @cbSelect parameter to the command
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Case", chkBox2.Checked)
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", gvRow.Cells(0).Text)
        Using (sqlcon)
            sqlcon.Open() 'open connection
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery() 'execute the command
        End Using
    Next
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        GridView1.DataSourceID = ""
        GridView1.DataSource = CustomersData()
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Else
        If ddlSearch.SelectedItem.Text = "Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID" Then
            lblName.Text = "Enter Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID:"
            lblMessage.Text = ""
        Else
            lblName.Text = "Enter Territory:"
            lblMessage.Text = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    If txtSearch.Text = "" Then
        lblMessage.Text = "Enter " & ddlSearch.SelectedItem.Text & " to search"
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        GridView1.DataSourceID = ""
        GridView1.DataSource = CustomersData()
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Else
        lblMessage.Text = ""
        GridView1.DataSourceID = ""
        GridView1.DataSource = CustomersDataWithSearchText(ddlSearch.SelectedItem.Text, txtSearch.Text)
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Some of the code at the ASPX level

```
   <div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblSearch" runat="server" Text="I want to Search"></asp:Label>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSearch" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
       <asp:ListItem>Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem>Territory</asp:ListItem>
       </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Enter Contact Name"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>

  </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting the error in CustomersData() or CustomersDataWithSearchText() or both?

Comment: Both unfortunately... :(

Comment: Can you specify at which position you are getting error now?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? and can you show me the layout of the table `BusinessSignups`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the column name Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID in your sql server table BusinessSignups, either the column name doesn't exist or it is different.

Comment: It's certainly there, I am using the same query in the grid view which returns the data ok. Having said that as you can see its "Sfdc Account Owner ID" in SQL server I am usign as in the SQL query to change this to Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID.

Comment: Your query states that your column name is Sfdc Account Owner ID and  Your alias is Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID which is opposite, change that.

Comment: Yup I had tried this before, with the same outcome. Specificlly I changed the following:
`code`

 If ddlSearch.SelectedItem.Text = "Sfdc Account Owner ID" Then
                lblName.Text = "Enter Sfdc Account Owner ID:"
                lblMessage.Text = ""
            Else
and on the ASPX
<asp:ListItem>Sfdc Account Owner ID</asp:ListItem>

Comment: Kindly replace code in your query from [Sfdc Account Owner ID] AS Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID to [sfdc_Account_Owner_ID] AS Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID

Comment: OR to [Sfdc Account Owner ID] AS  Sfdc Account Owner ID

Comment: Also change the database column name to  Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID for the first case and  Sfdc Account Owner ID for the second case

Comment: Changed as suggested now getting A field or property with the name 'Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID' was not found on the selected data source.

Comment: Now the field you have set in the grid or any other place as Sfdc_Account_Owner_ID should be changed to [Sfdc Account Owner ID]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @secretformula got it

Comment: yeah fixed that last refereance to the missing one.... now getting An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Account'.